# Openbox changes aren't taking effect at all on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mate, openbox

Im running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and I click the gear icon on login to use openbox. And no matter what changes I make to the rc.xml file and no matter if I restart it or reconfigure nothing happens at all. I've been trying to implement this

```
<!-- Window Tiling: Emulates Windows 7 Snap feature -->
<keybind key="W-Left">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <width>50%</width>
  </action>
  <action name="MoveToEdgeWest"/>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Right">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <width>50%</width>
  </action>
  <action name="MoveToEdgeEast"/>
</keybind>
```

to make windows like key bindings.

Comment: Try it while not running Mate.

Comment: @mikewhatever my feeling is that the OP is not logging into Ubuntu Mate but into an Openbox session. So Mate shouldn't be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rc.xml` file should be in `~/.config/openbox`. Back it up first and then please try:

```
<keybind key="W-Left">        # HalfLeftScreen
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>0</x><y>0</y><height>100%</height><width>50%</width></action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Right">        # HalfRightScreen
  <action name="Unmaximize"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo"><x>-0</x><y>0</y><height>100%</height><width>50%</width></action>
</keybind>
```

*Note: make sure that you are working in the `<keyboard>` section and not anywhere else!*

After you've edited and saved the modified `rc.xml`, open a terminal and run `openbox --reconfigure`. (You shouldn't get a pop-up informing you of parsing errors. If you do, you'll probably need to fix those.) Only then will the changes take effect. There's no need to restart anything.

**Addendum:**

The following keybinds can be used to minimize (aka Iconify) and maximize the active (in focus) window:

```
<keybind key="C-W-Up">        # Minimize
  <action name="Iconify"/>
</keybind>

<keybind key="C-W-Down">        # Maximize
  <action name="Maximize"/>
</keybind>
```

(I already use W-Up and W-Down for snapping to the top half and bottom half. You need to ensure that you don't use the same key combos twice! So do run through `rc.xml` before making your shortcut choices.)

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD. Made sure the code you gave was put in the keyboard section as well. Do you know how to maximize with win+up and minimize with win+down?THANK YOU SO MUCH AGAIN BTW